# java scheduling task with timer at specific time

Tags: java, timer

I have a database, from which I retrieve time of showing reminder (that is my task). The received time I put into timer, but it shows reminder not at this time but immediately at current time. What is the problem?

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next()){
   time=rs.getString   ("time");
}
timer = new Timer(); // Instantiate Timer Object
timer.schedule(new Task(), timeFormat.parse(time));
```

for example, the time of showing reminder is 17:10:00. but it shows at 17:00:00

Comment: Looks like the date info is missing, hence defaults to the blank date *(probably Jan 1 1970)*, which means the timer will run the task immediately. What is `timeFormat`? Is it a `SimpleDateFormat` object? Also what is the `time` string that you get from the database? Try storing an actual `TIMESTAMP` in the database and using `rs.getDate(String)` instead.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794313/how-to-schedule-a-task-at-specific-time
new TimerTask()

Comment: Thank you a lot. the problem was exactly as you wrote (after parsing time the date automatically became 01.01.1970). Solved it by concatenation actual date of reminder (it is stored in separate column in my database) and its time, all of which I retrieve like String. and only after that I parse with SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") and the result I set into my timer.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the timediffrence btween currentDatetime and reminderDatetime and get the milliseconds,then pass that millisecond in timer.schedule(new Task(),timediff) function.
just like below ,

```
private long ScheduleTime(String strpostDate) {

    long hrs = 0;
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    Date curDate = null;
    Date postDate = null;
    String curdate = formatter.format(new Date());
    try {
        curDate = (Date) formatter.parse(curdate);
        postDate = (Date) formatter.parse(strpostDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    long diffInMs = postDate.getTime() - curDate.getTime();
    return diffInMs;

}
```

your  function

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next()){
datetime=rs.getString   ("time");
}
timer = new Timer(); // Instantiate Timer Object
timer.schedule(new Task(), ScheduleTime(datetime));
```

Comment: What about [`Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, Date time)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date))? Surely if you have the `Date` you could just pass it to this method and have `Timer` class manage the delay calculation internally.. right?

Comment: Please check this link, may be you get your answer from this,http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm

Comment: My question is if you can build a `Date` object, why don't you pass it directly to the `schedule` method I quoted? You don't need to get the system date and calculate the millisecond delay. In fact, try returning `postDate` in your `ScheduleTime` method and see what happens!