# Kill thread in java after a certain time

Tags: java, multithreading, twitter, twitter4j

I have a use case as following (in **JAVA**)

I receive a request from client

E.g: Do twitter streaming task till this date.

- Task = twitter streaming
- Keywords = {"#Today", "#apple"}
- Time = till 5 feburary 2017

What I do is, ***I open a new thread on every request that I receive and start my task which is streaming of tweets and saving them to the database.***

What I want to do is the thread should stop streaming and should get killed after this date (Feb 5).

How can I implement this type of use-case?

Comment: Interrupt the thread.

Comment: Is the thread in a loop?  Can you check the current date and drop out once 5th Feb is reached?

Comment: Please add relevant code.

Comment: You have an example here. With two task, one executes the main program and the other is scheduled to interrupt the first one at specific time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794313/how-to-schedule-a-task-at-specific-time

Comment: Use a volatile boolean to control the loop (in the form while ! stop). When you read the first tweet after a certain date, just set stop to true.

Comment: existing the loop is one option, but is there any way better than that, e.g thread should die after the expiry time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Calendar` class and check that e.g.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of("CET")));
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1)
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5)
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);

while(true){
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of("CET")));
 if(cal.getTime().after(c.getTime()) return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any other way to achieve this without using while loop.

Comment: @PrakashPandey There is no built-in method for setting a expiry timer on a Thread. Either you do it by setting the expiry in the thread like my answer or one of the comments above where another object kills the Thread.

Comment: Murat, will  garbage collector remove all thread resource after `return;`?

Comment: @PrakashPandey Yes if you have no reference to the Thread anymore. If it was anonymous it will be garbage collected.

Comment: `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
  c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
  c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);
  c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
  c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 43);
  c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
  c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);`

Comment: Using this code I got this date `Thu Mar 02 20:43:00 IST 2017`.

It should be Feb instead of march.

Comment: @PrakashPandey If you are in a different TimeZone you have to adjust it.